# Restoring a veracrypt volume

Tags: hard-drive, software-raid, veracrypt

I had a great idea at one point, creating an asus motherboard raid 0, where i ultimately installed windows too (yes i know). One of the M.2 ssds, started failing and i had to reinstall everything.

Here comes the fun. When you install Asus raid, technically every disk is classified as a raid disk. Im unsure if you can undo that but whatever. They all get Classified as a raid disk in terms of windows seeing it.

I had a veracrypt disk (separate file, not the whole disk) stored on a separate HHD, which windows now cant read. I then had another great idea of deleting the partion via windows disk manager before realizing what i did.

I have tried running a couple of data recovery programs, none of them finding the encrypted veracrypt file named "data.txt". Is it not going to be able to read it because of the encryption? It is worth noting, it reads the directory of all other files right away, while its recovering everything. But not the txt file

Comment: "Is it not going to be able to read it because of the encryption?" - Was the volume the file was on encrypted?  If it was then data recovery will not be possible.

Comment: so since its not actually text data, and because it is unlikely that veracrypt volume-files have distinct header/footer information, and are potentially large (and thus potentially non-contigious), file carving utilities likely won't be able to find them without the filesystem being intact. if you can, recovering the whole partition (to other media of course) using a tool like testdisk may be your best bet.